# How to print the actual strings in an arraylist?

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist

I am trying to print the contents of an arraylist that I am using to store arrays of strings. Basically, I am trying to write a program that reads a file line by line, and stores the individual lines as separate arrays of strings in an arraylist. I want to check if it worked by printing the string arrays in the arraylist but currently my code is only printing the addresses. It looks like the following:

```
package Filecheck;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class FileImport {
    public static void main(String [] args) {

        // The name of the file to open.
        String fileName = "/Users/Frank/Desktop/test.rtf";

        String line;
        String[] name = null;
        ArrayList<String[]> list = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        try {

            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);

            BufferedReader readerB = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
            line = readerB.readLine();
            while((line = readerB.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
                name = line.split(" ");
                list.add(name);
            }
            for (int i=0; i < list.size(); i++){
                System.out.println(list.get(0).toString());
            }

            readerB.close();         
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println(
                "Unable to open file '" + 
                fileName + "'");                
        }
        catch(IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(
                "Error reading file '" 
                + fileName + "'");                  

        }
    }
}
```

The output of the code is as follows:

```
{\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Helvetica;}
{\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}
\margl1440\margr1440\vieww10800\viewh8400\viewkind0
\pard\tx720\tx1440\tx2160\tx2880\tx3600\tx4320\tx5040\tx5760\tx6480\tx7200\tx7920\tx8640\pardirnatural

\f0\fs24 \cf0 \
Test String The pens are going to win the cup\
Another Test}
[Ljava.lang.String;@533ded59
[Ljava.lang.String;@533ded59
[Ljava.lang.String;@533ded59
[Ljava.lang.String;@533ded59
[Ljava.lang.String;@533ded59
[Ljava.lang.String;@533ded59
[Ljava.lang.String;@533ded59
[Ljava.lang.String;@533ded59
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: It is because you are using String[] as your Object type for the list, also you should have list.get(i) not list.get(0).

Comment: What should be the object type instead? Thanks for the help

Comment: Well String since you just want line by line, I have no idea why you are trying to split with " ", since based on your output there are no spaces...

Comment: The plan was for each line to be its own individual array of words and then that array to be stored in the array list. So the array list would be made up of an array of strings that correspond to each word in the line of inputted text.

Comment: Change `System.out.println(list.get(0).toString());` to `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list.get(i)));`.

Comment: That worked!!! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Some easy options for this. There are a bunch of ways to do this and I can't cover all of them.

1) Consider whether you need to be storing a list of `String` arrays and instead just store a list of strings.

2) Create your own print array function and call that for each element as you iterate the array. An example implementation of this function could be

`public void printArray(T[] array) {
    for(T item : array) System.out.println(item);
}`

3) Convert your array or strings to a list of strings